# Calculating Odometry Data for the Navigation Stack

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I hope someone can help me answer a simple question. My custom robot delivers data. The data are velocity (m / s) and rotation velocity (deg / s or rad / s). I also recieve the distance the robot has traveled (mm). My problem is, I need to publish the odometry-data for the navigation-stack. I followed this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom). The tutorial calls for the vx and vy and vth coordinates. I have the vth coordinates but I need vx and vy and don´t know how to calculate them having only the velocity and the rotation velocity.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207546/calculating-odometry-data-for-the-navigation-stack/) by [Twista3579](https://answers.ros.org/users/21669/twista3579/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that your robot is non-holonomic (that it can only move forward and not side-to-side), then vy will always be 0 since your robot never moves on its Y axis. As for vx, it will simply be the velocity of your robot in m/s.

---

Originally posted by [yohtm](https://answers.ros.org/users/22234/yohtm/) with karma: 66 on 2015-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1